# get length of strings split into parts

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to get the length of silted strings in number or stringlist view

```
String s= "Aan.Gabriel.Gymkhana";
String[] parts = s.split("\\.");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
String part3

String s= "Aan.Gabriel.Gymkhana";
String[] parts = s.split("\\.");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
String part3
```

as list

```
1 Aan
2 Gabrie
3 Gymkhana
```

the length of list will be 3

Comment: 'silted', 'slited'... do you mean 'split'?

Comment: yes went to split it and set it in list strings

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. I suspect either `parts.length` or `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(parts)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "set it in list strings"? Do you mean you want to put it in a list of Strings? Get a list of the lengths of the strings? Get the number of parts the String was split into?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time figuring out what you want, but I think that `s.split("\\.").length` should get you the correct solution.

If you just need the length, then you don't need to turn it into a list.

If you want to turn it into a list, @Micheal's answer was correct.

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(parts);
```

Comment: but i went to get it separately in a list string